# Return a dynamically allocated array from C++ dll to VBA

Tags: c++, arrays, vba, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

DISCLAIMER: I *know* how to allocate memory in VBA, fill an array within a C++ DLL and return its pointer, **but** sadly I might find a couple of cases in which I cannot know the size of an array, therefore I won't be able to `Dim` or `ReDim` it in VBA, before passing it to the DLL.

Suppose I have a C++ subroutine inside my DLL, that would "return" two things as output: one is an integer and the other is an array:

```
void _stdcall mySub(int inOption, int outXPR, double* outWeight_Coeff)

// Do Stuff 

WindowThetaHalf = [insert random value here];
WindowPhiHalf = [insert random value here];
outXPR = value;

outWeight_Coeff = new double[(WindowThetaHalf + 1) * (WindowPhiHalf + 1)];

for (int i = -WindowThetaHalf; i <= WindowThetaHalf; i++)
{
    for (int j = -WindowPhiHalf; j <= WindowPhiHalf; j++)
    {
        outWeight_Coeff[i + WindowThetaHalf + j * (WindowThetaHalf + 1) * 2 + WindowPhiHalf] = i + j;
    }
}
```

Now, I know that I have to give to the DLL the first element of an array as a pointer to make this work:

```
Private Declare Sub mySub Lib "[dll path here]" (ByVal inOption As Long, ByVal XPR As Long, ByRef outWeight_Coeff As Double)

Sub main()

Dim XPR As Long
Dim a() As Double

ReDim a(0, 0)
LoadChannelType 1, XPR, a(0, 0)

Debug.Print XPR
For i = 0 To UBound(a, 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(a, 2)
        Debug.Print a(i, j)
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

This doesn't work though. I feel it might have something to do with the dimensions I'm specifying in VBA, but again, it is very possible that I will have to deal with a situation in which I'd basically have to "`ReDim`" the `outWeight_Coeff` array in C++ .
Is there any possibility to do that?

EDIT: Other ways I tried and failed:

Instead of using `new`, I tried the following as well:

- Using `malloc`:

  ```
  outWeight_Coeff = (double*)malloc(((WindowThetaHalf + 1) * (WindowPhiHalf + 1)) * sizeof(double));
  ```
- Creating a new array and assigning the pointer to it:

  ```
  double* newArr = new double [(WindowThetaHalf + 1) * (WindowPhiHalf + 1)];
  outWeight_Coeff = newArr;
  ```

Comment: Just from the first look - `XPR` should be long in the VBA code, not `integer`. C++ integer is VBA long.

Comment: Yes, sorry... Copy-Paste stupidity got me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ prototype:

```
void __stdcall mySub(int inOption, int outXPR, VARIANT *outWeight_Coeff)
```

VBA prototype:

```
Private Declare Sub mySub Lib "[dll path here]" (ByVal inOption As Long, ByVal XPR As Long, ByRef outWeight_Coeff As Variant)
```

This approach allows you to resize the array in C++ (SafeArrayRedim), and/or create a new array and replace whatever array was passed in the argument.

The simplest way to implement that is by using ATL classes `CComVariant` and `CComSafeArray<double>`. Don’t forget to use Attach/Detach for the CComVariant, otherwise you might leak memory.

Unfortunately, if you don’t have experience with COM automation in C++, you’ll spend some time implementing that even with ATL utility classes: Attach/Detach, VT_BYREF, different lower bounds, etc., it’s relatively cumbersome for a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks, that basically solved it. I transformed my Sub in a function instead, creating there the array I needed as a `SAFEARRAY` and then passing it to VBA as `VARIANT`

Comment: Good idea: returning VARIANT is simpler than messing with these byref parameters.